# Flex : Multy row TabBar?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, flex4.5

- Is it possible, and how to do it ( if it is ) to have a multy row TabBar, based on the width of the container ?

Comment: Im not sure exactly how do to this, but extending TabBar is a good way to start. Have u seen this [link]http://blog.everythingflex.com/2009/08/27/multirowtabs-flex-component-redux/ ? Maybe that will be of some help to you, although the full source code link is broken. Also i know it's not what u asked for, but if you do not like the normal TabBar, the SuperTabBar from [link]http://code.google.com/p/flexlib/wiki/ComponentList is kinda nice :)

Comment: I guess you could apply a TileLayout to a custom TabBarSkin instead of HorizontalLayout. This way you wouldn't even have to extend TabBar

Comment: I have added TileLayout but there is some strange gap which is leaving constanly below the tabs. :|

Comment: I built one back in the Flex 2 days; but we decided not to release it because it was against our "goal" of helping people create intuitive user interfaces.  I think our component strung multiple tab bars together.

Comment: @YordanYanakiev Have you tried setting the 'horizontalGap' and 'verticalGap' of the layout to '0' or maybe even '-1'?

Comment: <s:TileLayout horizontalGap="-1" verticalGap="-1" columnWidth="80" /> yes i did, but still the wried gap occuring :|

Comment: Perhaps the issue is in the TabBarButtonSkin then? It may have some padding at the top.

Comment: I just did a quick test with just the TileLayout: works perfectly. Do you have custom skins that might mess things up?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's as simple as giving your TabBar a TileLayout. You don't have to subclass TabBar and you don't even have to create a custom skin class for it. Just do this:

```
<s:TabBar dataProvider="{dp}" left="0" right="0">
    <s:layout>
        <s:TileLayout horizontalGap="-1" verticalGap="-1" 
                      requestedRowCount="2" />
    </s:layout>
</s:TabBar>
```

Which will produce something like this:

[image: TabBar with TileLayout]

The gap below the TabBar you saw, is produced because TileLayout will by default allocate a certain number of rows. You can override this by setting the `requestedRowCount` to the number of rows you expect (2 in this example).

If you want it to be truly dynamic, you can calculate the required number of rows by comparing the TabBar's total `width` to the TileLayout's `columnWidth`, and bind the resulting number to the `requestedRowCount` property.

Comment: it does work, but still a wried gap occurring after the TabBar object. :| <s:TabBar id="mainTabNavigator" width="100%"  dataProvider="{ dataProvidersTabs }" >
  <s:layout>
   <s:TileLayout horizontalGap="-1" verticalGap="-1" />
  </s:layout>
 </s:TabBar> this is inside <VGroup> if it is helping somehow. Flex 4.6.

Comment: @YordanYanakiev I've updated my answer with a fix for that issue.

Comment: height="{(int(dataProvidersTabs.length/(width/90))+1)*21}" this is another fix, but maybe there is much beutiful solution.

Comment: about requestedRowCount - this actually do the job done! Thank you very very much RIAstar :)