# tab navigator but spread over two rows in flex

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, tabnavigator

I currently use a Tab Navigator in my flex project and ideally I would like to continue to use it but the problem is there is quite a few tabs and almost all of them end in "..." because their is not enough space to display the entire header. is it possible to display the navigator over two rows? 
I'm quite new to flex so if this is an easy thing then apologies.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but perhaps you can use it as inspiration: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9718895/flex-multy-row-tabbar/9724019#9724019

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the following link can help you out. Just Check this...

Hope it will help

http://flexponential.com/2011/10/23/enable-scrolling-in-the-tab-bar-of-a-tabbedviewnavigator/

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Spark Tab Bar, the answer from the link above will work. If you are using the old Halo Tab Navigator, there is an excellent component, [SuperTabNavigator](http://dougmccune.com/flex/supertabnavigator/SuperTabNavigator_Sample.html) available as a part of [Flex lib.](https://github.com/flex-users/flexlib)